# Removing Unicode U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK like ‘Ali to Ali in swift

Tags: swift, string, diacritics

How to remove Unicode U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK from strings like -

Ghulam ‘Ali, ‘Ali Khel,‘Ali Sher ‘Alaqahdari.

I want to remove occurrences of ‘A || ‘a || ‘U || ‘u in a string to A a U u respectively.

I tried

```
var myString = "Sozmah Qal‘ah"
var diacriticRemovedString = myString.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: Locale.current)
print(diacriticRemovedString)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: The code you posted is Swift 2 code.

Comment: Are `‘` considered diacritics? It's Unicode U+2018  LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the U+2018 character doesn't appear to be treated as a diacritic, you can simple search for such characters and remove them.

Here is the Swift 4 version (as specified in your original question) that removes diacritics and these specific quotation marks:

```
var myString = "Sozmah Qal‘ah"
var diacriticRemovedString = myString.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: Locale.current).replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "")
print(diacriticRemovedString)
```

Output:

> Sozmah Qalah