# Remove ' from a string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, replace

I have an issue with removing a character from a string in Swift 5.
I want to remove the occurrence of the character ' and when Ii run in playground it seems to work, however in my project not so.

Playground. Works fine and result it "Hello Playground."

```
var str = "Hello, playground'."

print(str.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: ""))
```

However here is my code snippet

```
 strName = inputTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) ?? ""

 print(strName)
 print(strName.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: ""))
```

This results in the the same string being printed twice.
test's
test's

strName is declared as such

```
var strName: String = " "
```

Comment: Probably your input field does not contain an apostrophe, but a left or right single quotation mark. That are different characters. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Unicode_code_point_table.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/50589284/1187415.

Comment: Thank you. worked a treat remove based on the diacriticInsensitive folding option